# How to iterate through dynamic Pivot table with Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

On a daily input I receive, I do a pivot table, which I created manually once. The pivot table has active filters. Once I get the new input, I refresh the pivot. In a simplified way, it looks like this:

[image: Pivot Table]

With a small VBA macro, I would like to retrieve the person's name and the countries he visited and then do a check on that two values. How can I iterate through this dynamic pivot table in order to get for every row the name and the country (e.g. Name = Amanda, Country = Spain)?

Comment: Can you share the data so that we don't have to type all that stuff?

Comment: Why would you have to type that "stuff"?

Comment: To test what I think could be a solution

Comment: Also note what the C is in this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you - since it isn't about reproducing a specific problem but rather about a generic approach, I didn't think providing some random data would help. However I am glad to provide a random data example here: http://pastebin.com/T95XY9Wk - thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will loop through A column and populate two variables, Country and Name.
And for debug purpose I output a string.

```
Sub Travel()

    Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 4 To Lastrow ' Change i to first row with a name in pivot table
        If Range("A" & i).IndentLevel = 0 Then ' New person
            Name = Range("A" & i).Value
            Country = ""
        Else
            Country = Range("A" & i).Value
        End If

        If Country <> "" Then
            ' For debug purpose
            Range("C" & i).Value = Name & " was in " & Country
        Else
            ' The code is "in between" two names
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. I will test it today in the office and get back to you asap